# How do you unescape URLs in Java?

Tags: java, url-encoding

When I read the xml through a URL's InputStream, and then cut out everything except the url, I get "http://cliveg.bu.edu/people/sganguly/player/%20Rang%20De%20Basanti%20-%20Tu%20Bin%20Bataye.mp3".

As you can see, there are a lot of "%20"s.

I want the url to be unescaped.

Is there any way to do this in Java, without using a third-party library?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, there is no such thing as "normal unicode". UTF8 is one of several ways to represent unicode text. But there is no "true" canonical representation.

Comment: As Jon and ng said, this has nothing to do with Unicode or UTF-8.  You might want to change the title.

Comment: The answer marked as correct now it is clearly wrong and should be removed.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is not unescaped XML, this is URL encoded text. Looks to me like you want to use the following on the URL strings.

```
URLDecoder.decode(url);
```

This will give you the correct text. The result of decoding the like you provided is this.

```
http://cliveg.bu.edu/people/sganguly/player/ Rang De Basanti - Tu Bin Bataye.mp3
```

The %20 is an escaped space character. To get the above I used the URLDecoder object.

Comment: That method is deprecated. Use URLDecoder.decode(location,"UTF-8");

Answer (score 19):

## Starting from Java 11 use

## [`URLDecoder.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset)).

for Java 7/8/9 use [`URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

`URLDecoder.decode(String s)` has been deprecated since **Java 5**

Regarding the chosen encoding:

> Note: The [World Wide Web Consortium Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars) states that **UTF-8** should be used. Not doing so may introduce incompatibilites.

Comment: for Java 8 & 9 Use `URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Since Java 7 [StandardCharsets](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.java#L52). Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but the URLDecoder method `decode` only takes (String, String) in Java 8

Comment: @user16320675 I'd considered that - but will it work with the underscore rather than hyphen in "UTF-8" ?

Comment: Thank you to share.  I never knew about this handy method before I read this answer! 
 One cool feature of `URLDecoder.decode()` vs `new URI().getPath()`: The `URI` ctor will reject decoded URLs!  `URLDecoder.decode()` will accept both encoded and decoded URLs, e.g., (decoded) `/path/to/here and there` and (encoded) `/path/to/here%20and%20there`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems using this method when I have special characters like `á`, `é`, `í`, etc. My (probably wild) guess is widechars are not being encoded properly... well, at least I was expecting to see sequences like `%uC2BF` instead of `%C2%BF`.

Edited: My bad, this post explains the difference between URL encoding and JavaScript's escape sequences: [URI encoding in UNICODE for apache httpclient 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280863/uri-encoding-in-unicode-for-apache-httpclient-4)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the URL contained escaped html entities, so `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()` from apache-commons did the trick