# Java: how to get a File from an escaped URL?

Tags: java, file, url, escaping

I'm receiving an URL that locates a local file (the fact that I receive an URL is not in my control).  The URL is escaped validly as defined in RFC2396.  How can I transform this to a Java File object?

Funnily enough, the URL getFile() method returns a String, not a File.

I've created a directory called "/tmp/some dir" (with a spacing character between "some" and "dir"), which is correctly located by the following URL: "file:///tmp/some%20dir"  (quotes added for clarity).

How can I convert that URL to a Java File?

To give more detail about my issue, the following prints false:

```
URL url = new URL( "file:///tmp/some%20dir" );
File f = new File( url.getFile() );
System.out.println( "Does dir exist? " + f.exists() );
```

While the following (manually replacing "%20" with a space) prints true:

```
URL url = new URL( "file:///tmp/some%20dir" );
File f = new File( url.getFile().replaceAll( "%20", " " ) );
System.out.println( "Does dir exist? " + f.exists() );
```

Note that I'm not asking *why* the first example prints false nor *why* the second example using my hacky *replaceAll* prints true, I'm asking how to convert an escaped URL into a Java File object.

**EDIT**: thanks all, this was nearly a dupe but not exactly.

Stupidly I was looking for a helper method inside the URL class itself.

The following works as expected to get a Java File from a Java URL:

```
URL url = new URL( "file:///home/nonet/some%20dir" );
File f = new File( URLDecoder.decode( url.getFile(), "UTF-8" ) );
```

Comment: See also http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/how_to_convert.html for a caveat.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
URLDecoder.decode(url);//deprecated
URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"); //use this instead
```

See related question [How do you unescape URLs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623861/how-do-you-unescape-urls-in-java)

Comment: This method is deprecated. Use this one instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213506/java-net-urlencoder-encodestring-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: If the URL is RFC2396-encoded (e.g. it came from `file.toURI()` or `new URI("file", null, file.getPath(), null)`), then **do not** decode it using [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)! For example, if the file were “`main.c++`”, then URLDecoder would decode it as as “`main.c  `”. URLDecoder is only used for decoding HTML form submissions. This is mentioned in the bottom of the [URL javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Comment: In case anyone is using Apache Commons IO take a look at FileUtils.toFile(URL) which should decode the URL properly (even if the path contains symbols such as + and &)

Answer (score 71):

The [`File` constructor taking an `URI`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) in combination with [`URL#toURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29) should work:

```
URL url = getItSomehow();
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: Well ... you only answered the part about getting the file from the URL.  But hey, its the OP's choice as to which answer he thinks is *most* helpful.

Comment: Loved it too, seems to be the best answer. If only toURI wouldn't throw that nasty URISyntaxException...

Comment: @Stijn: `URLDecoder#decode()` is also not free of checked exceptions. Either way, just add `throws IOException` to the method.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK like this `Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile()` is best, starting with Java 7. See also [Converting Java file:// URL to File(...) path, platform independent, including UNC paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520972/converting-java-file-url-to-file-path-platform-independent-including-u).