# Referencing the Desktop with a URL

Tags: java, file, url, desktop

I have been looking on Google for a while now, and I just cant seem to find or remember how to access a file on the desktop with a `URL`.  It's really frustrating me. Here is what I feel like it should be:

```
URL url = new URL("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Desktop\\hi.gif");
```

But it is just not working. I believe there is something that I should put instead of `new URL` but I cant find it. I've tried every search term I can think of.

How to turn file path as `String` into `URL`?

Comment: file:/// should do the trick.

See also:
----------
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166039/java-how-to-get-a-file-from-an-escaped-url

Comment: @dctucker  *"file:/// should do the trick."* That fails to produce a valid URL when the file name has spaces.  Valid URLs should also only contain forward slash `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// There are better ways to specify file paths, BNI.
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Austin\\Desktop\\hi.gif");
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
```

Comment: +1 for quick response and an answer that worked the first time! thanks man!

Comment: i had to wait a few days for some reason