# Runtime.exec() fails with space in directory (Java)

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute a process in the same directory as my Jar file by getting the location of the file with

```
private static File jarLocation = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParentFile();
```

then calling

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command", null, jarLocation);
```

This usually works just fine but when the path has a space in it I get "The directory name is invalid". I have attempted to add some debug code which prints the path of the directory which has replaced spaces with "%20" (I assume because the ASCII hex of space is 20). is there a way to be able to use a directory with spaces in its path?

Comment: replacing %20 back to actual spaces should work. They are result of url encoding. Edit: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733172/995891

Comment: Can you include the full error you're getting, including stack trace? What OS are you running this on? And the actual `command` string? It is tokenized in this form of Runtime.exec(), so there could be issues there.

Comment: @AndrewJanke The command I am running does not seem to make any difference. I haved tried this on both Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu) and it also does not seem to make any difference. I am just passing a string for the command.

Comment: Okay. Then it's probably just a matter of decoding the URL path to get the right `jarLocation`. See answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `getPath()` call, which is `URL.getPath()`, does not return a filesystem path. It returns the path portion of a URL. In the case of a `file:` URL, it will be a URL-encoded local filesystem path. If that original URL is in fact a `file:` URL, you need to use the URI and URL classes, or custom string processing, to convert that to a local filesystem path that the `Runtime.exec()` can work with.

This might work directly in your case.

```
File jarLocation = Paths.get(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).toFile();
```

You can also see the discussion at [Converting Java file:// URL to File(...) path, platform independent, including UNC paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520972/converting-java-file-url-to-file-path-platform-independent-including-u).