# Convert windows path to URI in Java?

Tags: java, windows, path, uri

What is in Java the correct way to create a file URI **for Windows**? I tried

```
new URI("file", null, file.getAbsolutePath(), null);
```

but this complains about a relative path used in an absolute URI. I also tried prefixing the path with `"//"`, but this makes 'c:' into a hostname. Then I prefixed the path with `"////"`. A subsequent `uri.getPath()` then has a leading `"//"`, which still does not seem right.

Is there any clean way to go from `file.getAbsolutePath()` to a URI with `file://` protocol and back to a Windows path usable for `new File(...)` on Windows?

Comment: Did u look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520972/converting-java-file-url-to-file-path-platform-independent-including-u

Comment: Sorry guys, yes, I did searches and following proposed links when writing the question, but did not hit on the other one for some reason. I'll flag this one as duplicate myself.

Answer (score 4):

check File class docs. it provide toURI() method. below code seemed give output:

File file = new File("d:/myfolder/myfile.txt");
System.out.println(file.toURI());

Comment: you probably mean toURI(), not toURL().

Comment: @Harald Yes right. That was typo mistake. Thanks for pointing :)