# java.io.IOException- can't create file in build folder

Tags: java, gradle

Java project build by Gradle.

I want to create file in `\build\resources\main\db\sqlite\insert-data.sql`

I try this:

```
  protected File getDestinationFile(String baseDir) {
    try {
        URL testURL = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("db/sqlite");
        String pathName = testURL + "/" + DEFAULT_FILE_NAME_INSERT_DATA;
        logger.debug("pathName = " + pathName);
        File newFile = new File(pathName);
        newFile.createNewFile();
        return newFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I get error on runtime:

```
[17.06.2022 00:19:38.223] MyClass.getDestinationFile(SQLiteStrategy.java:170) ERROR:
   java.io.IOException: 
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

Comment: What does `testURL` look like? Maybe it doesn't point to where you expect it.

Comment: A resource is not a file, it is data packaged in a JAR.

Comment: Alternatively, look at [How to include SQLite database in executable Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar) if you want to open a read-only sqlite database.

Comment: @akarnokd  pathName = file:/C:/dev/temp/m2cm/app/build/resources/main/db/sqlite/insert-data.sql

Comment: That's not a valid file name. There is URL to URI to File chain to get a valid File object https://stackoverflow.com/a/54123394/61158