# Java URL download returns meta refresh tag instead of content

Tags: java, http, download, http-equiv

I have an URL of a file - for example:

```
Http://www.anyUrl.com/fileExample
```

which is offering to download this file when pasting it in Chrome/Explorer

I want to get this file using Java code.

Tried doing it using:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.....");  InputStream......
or
DataInputStream ;
or
file = new File("https://www.....");
```

as well as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166039/java-how-to-get-a-file-from-an-escaped-url).

None of them works for me.

All I got was something that looks like this:

```
</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0
```

which is not the content of the given file.

How can it be done in Java?

Comment: not any url works or just some specific urls?

Comment: specific url of a file

Comment: How could we know what content that url has or how you iterated the contents? You need to post more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing you need to do is prove that the URL is actually providing a file.  You can do this by entering the URL in a browser and see what comes back.  Once your happy that the content of URL is a file you can use the examples here https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html to download the file.  See extracted example below.

```
Request.Get("http://targethost/homepage").execute().returnContent();
```