# Must use UTF-16 Url encoding to submit a search in Java. How can I?

Tags: java, url-encoding, utf-16

A certain site (which is not under my control) has an internal search engine that uses GET requests that look like: `something.com/search?query=%u0001%0101`, which I would like to use in my Java code .

To my understanding this is a not so common way (UTF-16) to do Url encoding. I tried using HttpURLConnection with a Url of the above type, but this throws me a `java.net.URISyntaxException Malformed escape pair at index X` (X being the position of the %u0001).

What can I do? I'm pretty new to these url encoding issues, so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you must double-encode? First to UTF-16 then URL-encoding?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but perhaps this will clarify: First I encode the unicode chars to ASCII to match the site's syntax (fake e.g. %$# -> %u0000%u0002%u0500), then I create a URL from them, and try to open a connection. So my code is something like: Url("something.com/search?query=%u0000%u0002%u0500").openConnection();

Comment: For my specific case, [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280863/uri-encoding-in-unicode-for-apache-httpclient-4) solved the problem. Though I have not tried, my searches came to the conclusion that @McDowell has a correct and more general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `something.com/search?query=%u0001%0101` violates the URI specification as percentage characters are reserved for [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). Under this rule, a percentage symbol must be followed by two hexadecimal digits. This is not a valid UTF-16 encoded URI.

It is not surprising that errors are thrown on these addresses.

You may have to resort to opening a [socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and sending your own malformed [client request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request).

```
GET /search?query=%u0001%0101 HTTP/1.1
Host: something.com
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess you are right, and that's what I would have done, had I not found out another way that "accidentally" works in my case... (answered my own question eventually)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.net.URLEncoder.encode("you string", "UTF-16");`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks. I think this method encodes to a different format from the one I'm looking for. It creates: %00%01 ASCII, instead of the %u0001 format the site I'm trying to use needs.

Comment: @DannyA What string are you encoding and what are you expecting it to look like afterwards?

Comment: The string could be anything I would like to search (e.g. "דני") and the result I need is something in the above format (e.g. "%u05D3%u05E0%u05D9" for this example). But the specific ASCII format of the unicode is less of a problem (I could play with the chars a bit). The problem, to my understanding, is that the URL with this (%uXXXX) encoding is considered malformed by java's libs.