# Unescape url in java

Tags: java, url

I am trying to unescape a URL in java.

Is there some tool or library for that ?

```
example : filter=Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.
```

I need this in the normal form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unescape URLs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623861/how-do-you-unescape-urls-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`URLDecoder.decode(String s,"utf-8")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will work if `s` is encoded in [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode("filter=Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.", "utf-8");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
filter=Screen Refresh Rate|120HZ^Screen Size|37 in. to 42 in.
```