# Convert encoded string to readable string in java

Tags: java, c#, string, unicode, encoding

I am trying to send a POST request from a C# program to my java server.
I send the request together with an json object.
I recive the request on the server and can read what is sent using the following java code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
String line = reader.readLine();
String contentLengthString = "Content-Length: ";
int contentLength = 0;
while(line.length() > 0){   
    if(line.startsWith(contentLengthString))
        contentLength = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(contentLengthString.length()));             
    line = reader.readLine();
}       
char[] temp = new char[contentLength];
reader.read(temp);  
String s = new String(temp);
```

The string s is now the representation of the json object that i sent from the C# client. However, some characters are now messed up.
Original json object:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

recived string:

```
%7b%22key1%22%3a%22value1%22%2c%22key2%22%3a%22value2%22%2c%22key3%22%3a%22value3%22%%7d
```

So my question is: How do I convert the recived string so it looks like the original one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you unescape URLs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623861/how-do-you-unescape-urls-in-java)

Comment: That duplicate is a bad one. The author of the accepted answer never bothered to update their answer (which uses a deprecated method call). The answers below here are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like URL Encoded so why not use  `java.net.URLDecoder`

```
String s = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(new String(temp), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This is assuming the Charset is in fact `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Those appear the be URL encoded, so I'd use [`URLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html), like so

```
String in = "%7b%22key1%22%3a%22value1%22%2c%22key2"
    + "%22%3a%22value2%22%2c%22key3%22%3a%22value3%22%7d";
try {
  String out = URLDecoder.decode(in, "UTF-8");
  System.out.println(out);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note you seemed to have an extra percent in your example, because the above prints

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```